# Need LINQ Method Syntax Equivalent To LINQ Query Syntax - Compound Query (C# - Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, linq

I do have the following code in C# (Visual Studio 2008). This is LINQ Query syntax. I need equivalent in LINQ Method syntax. Can you help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 };

    var pairs = from a in numbersA
                from b in numbersB
                where a < b
                select new { a, b };

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is less than {1}", pair.a, pair.b);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming maybe you are looking for the lamba expressions, so This will produce the same output, but more condensed and accurate.

```
var res = numbersA.Zip<int, int, string>(numbersB, (a, b) => (a < b) ? a + " is less than " + b : a + " is greater than " + b).ToList();

res.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

If you have to spell them all out. I guess you could do this too:

```
var result = numbersA.SelectMany(c => numbersB, (c, o) => new { c, o })
                     .Where(d => d.c < d.o)
                     .Select(v => v.c + " is less than" + v.o);
                     
result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Hi mathis1337, I just need equivalent of                                                                                var pairs = from a in numbersA
                  from b in numbersB
                  where a < b
                  select new { a, b }

Comment: then the 2nd query is what you need